# SDL_MapRGB is crashing with no error message

Tags: c, sdl

I encounter a specific problem while i'm using SDL_MapRGB on my file **jeu.c** i'm trying to make a videogame and because i'm learning C, I wanted to improve my code by using a structure:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include "constantes.h"
#include "jeu.h"
#include "editeur.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
                    Partie *jeu = NULL;
                    jeu = (Partie *)malloc(sizeof(Partie));
                    if (jeu ==NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr,"Problème d'allocation de mémoire");
                    return 1;
                    }

SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL, *menu = NULL;
SDL_Rect positionMenu;
SDL_Event event;

int continuer = 1;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"probleme d'init video: %s\n", SDL_GetError ());
    };
SDL_WM_SetIcon(IMG_Load("img/icone.png"), NULL); // L'icône doit être chargée avant SDL_SetVideoMode
ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(LARGEUR_FENETRE, HAUTEUR_FENETRE, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
printf("Mode vidéo: dx%d\n", ecran->w, ecran->h, ecran->format->BitsPerPixel);
SDL_WM_SetCaption("pacman", NULL);

menu = IMG_Load("img/menu.png");
positionMenu.x = 0;
positionMenu.y = 0;

while (continuer)
{
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
    switch(event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            continuer = 0;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    continuer = 0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_RETURN: //
                    jouer (ecran);
                    break;
                case SDLK_SPACE: // Demande à jouer
                    jouer (ecran);
                    break;
                    case SDLK_KP_ENTER: // Demande à jouer
                    jouer (ecran);
                    break;
                case SDLK_KP1: // Demande à jouer
                    jouer (ecran);
                    break;
                case SDLK_KP2: // Demande l'éditeur de niveaux
                    editeur(ecran);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    SDL_FillRect(ecran, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255, 255, 255));
    SDL_BlitSurface(menu, NULL, ecran, &positionMenu);
    SDL_Flip(ecran);
}
SDL_FreeSurface(menu);
SDL_Quit();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**constantes.h**

```
#ifndef DEF_CONSTANTES
#define DEF_CONSTANTES
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#define TAILLE_BLOC         25 
#define NB_BLOCS_LARGEUR    28
#define NB_BLOCS_HAUTEUR    28
#define LARGEUR_FENETRE     TAILLE_BLOC * NB_BLOCS_LARGEUR
#define HAUTEUR_FENETRE     TAILLE_BLOC * NB_BLOCS_HAUTEUR


enum {HAUT, BAS, GAUCHE, DROITE};
enum {VIDE, MUR, GRAINE, ENNEMI, BONUS, PACMAN};

struct partie
{
 SDL_Surface * ecran;
 int score;
};
typedef struct partie Partie;
#endif
```

and here come the **jeu.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include "constantes.h"
#include "jeu.h"

int jouer(Partie * jeu)
{


SDL_Surface * ecran;
SDL_FillRect(ecran, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(jeu->ecran->format, 0, 0, 0));
```

after this line starting with SDL_FillRect i dont know why but whatever i'm writing the program is crashing. I locate this problem by using a lot of printf..
I also try this instead :

```
SDL_Surface * ecran;
Uint32 couleur=SDL_MapRGB(jeu->ecran->format, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_FillRect(jeu->ecran, NULL, couleur);
```

and the program crashed before SDL_FILLRect

I know this is hard to read noob code, but I spent all my day on this problem for no solutions.
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling `SDL_FillRect()` on an uninitialized pointer to `SDL_Surface` - which is either `NULL` or invalid and your code crashes right away (the lucky case) or happens to point to a valid memory location (and you end up corrupting your programs memory).

Depending on how you plan to use it later, either allocate some memory for your surface on the heap

```
SDL_Surface *ecran = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface));
```

or just put the whole thing on the stack and pass it's address to SDL_FillRect (maybe the better option if you don't plan to use it outside the `jouer` function

```
SDL_Surface ecran;
SDL_FillRect(&ecran, ...)
```